# One click and drag -- please make it stop

Tags: mouse

Using Chrome in Ubunutu 16.04; 
Every time I click once on a hyperlink and slightly move the mouse, it drags a shadow of the text across the screen instead of clicking through to the link. [ see grey box in image] This is something that happens 1000x a day and drive me up the wall.

Is there a way to disable that?

[image]

Comment: Such problem sounds like too big mouse sensitivity or acceleration, and that you can change in settings.